# URL Redirection Issue after WordPress update 5.5 version

Tags: url, redirect, wordpress-5.5

Currently i am facing issue with URL automatic redirection after the update Wordpress version 5.5 from 5.4. my URL is like http://localhost/testpage/214554 and last segment(214554) is my custom number that I have stored in database. and I have assigned one page template on testpage and through this number segment I have fetch data from the database and it was working fine till version 5.4 but after the updated version 5.5, When I try to load above url then last number segment is gone automatically and redirecting to the http://localhost/testpage instead of http://localhost/testpage/214554 so can you please help me to resolve my issue. It will good for me if anyone know how can I overcome from this issue.